# Using Paho mqtt js library in asp.net core app

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I have an issue when opening a web socket to my mosquitto broker. I'm using js MQTT client library opening a web socket between my browser and my mosquitto broker. In my web app, I have users authentication. When I hadn't user authentication my web socket worked fine but now I just want authenticated users to be able to see some data. My js code is the following:

```
console.log("clientId" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100))
client = new Paho.Client("my_ip", my_port, "clientId" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100));
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

client.connect({
    userName: "mosquitto",
    password: "moSquitto#52891",
    onSuccess: onConnect
});

function onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("onConnect");
    client.subscribe("ExtDataCE");
    client.subscribe("ExternDataTrain");
    client.subscribe("InfoMarker");
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
   if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:" + responseObject.errorMessage + " ErrorCode = " + responseObject.errorCode);
   }
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
//whatever
}
```

My controller looke like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Map()
    {
        return View("Map");
    }
}
```

When I run this code separated it works fine but when I run this code with a user authenticated my error is the following:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://ipaddress:port/mqtt' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

This is my mosquitto.log file

[image]

And my mosquitto config file

[image]

Anyone knows how can I do to make it work? I think it's something related to multiple services and/or multiple users trying to open a web socket or something like this. I tried it with chrome and firefox.
Any help? Thank you

Comment: Edit the question to include the mosquitto.conf to show how you enabled authentication and the logs from mosquitto from a failed connection.

Comment: I don't see anything that enables authentication in the mosquitto.conf file

Comment: What kind of authentication I have to enable? (I have a user and a password for the MQTT connection) @hardillb

Comment: Where have you configured mosquitto to check username/password against a list of allowed users?

Comment: In the directory /etc/mosquitto/conf.d I have a file called auth.conf that has two lines. One is: allow_anonymous flase, and the other is password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd (in this file I have the encrypted password). I authenticate the user when in the client.connect method I write user: "mosquitto" and password: "moSquitto#52891"@hardillb